# Identifying sequential patterns

Tags: sequence-analysis, sequential-pattern-mining

I am working with sequence data which are long lists of malware win-api calls. I am trying to cast the problem of identifying 'malware behavior' into one of finding sequential patterns. I treat each api call as a single item Itemset. The number of different possible items (api calls) is quite large.

Now, when I apply the [SPADE algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Sequence_Mining/SPADE) (see also, Zaki, [SPADE: An Efficient Algorithm for Mining Frequent Sequences](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~zaki/PS/MLJ01.pdf), Machine Learning, 42, 31–60, 2001) I run into memory problems.
Is there a better alternative way to find sequential patterns among large high vocabulary sequences?

Comment: Could you use a Markov-Chain Monte-Carlo approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can map the data into a feature space where sequence is important, along with both statistics calculated over sliding windows & cumulative statistics, and use that in a decision tree.

A decision tree could handle both sequences and non-sequential data.  This may substantially reduce your data complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You may try other sequential pattern mining algorithm.

For example, the [open-source SPMF java data mining library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) offers SPADE, but also PrefixSpan, SPAM, CM-SPAM, CM-SPADE, GSP, etc  (by the way, I'm the project founder).  To my knowledge CM-SPADE usually is faster than SPADE.  In terms of memory perhaps that SPAM uses less memory..  You could try it.